# This code allows people to navigate through some artworks

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css

I am new to coding and I have finished a code for a project I have given myself. Everything is functioning the way I want but I was wondering if maybe I could have done some things differently in a more concise way? I'd appreciate it if you could look at my code and help me re-code some elements that could be done in a more efficient way.

How can it be coded more efficiently?

```js
 function HideDivShowContent() {
               var v = document.getElementById("E1");
               if (v.style.display === "none") {
                  v.style.display = "block";
               } else {
                  v.style.display = "none";
               }
               var u = document.getElementById("Participants");
               u.style.display = "block";

            }

            function HideDivShowContent() {
               var v = document.getElementById("Participants");
               if (v.style.display === "none") {
                  v.style.display = "block";
               } else {
                  v.style.display = "none";
               }
               var u = document.getElementById("E1");
               u.style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById("E1").scrollIntoView();
            }
            
            function hideDivShowE2() {
    var x = document.getElementById('E1');
    if (x.style.display == 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var u = document.getElementById("E2");
       u.style.display = "block";
}

function hideE2ShowS1() {
    var x = document.getElementById('E2');
    if (x.style.display == 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var u = document.getElementById("sec1");
       u.style.display = "block";
}
function hideS1ShowE2() {
    var x = document.getElementById('sec1');
    if (x.style.display == 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var u = document.getElementById("E2");
       u.style.display = "block";
       
    document.getElementById("E2").scrollIntoView();
}
function hideE2ShowS2() {
    var x = document.getElementById('E2');
    if (x.style.display == 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var u = document.getElementById("sec2");
       u.style.display = "block";
}
function hideS2ShowE2() {
    var x = document.getElementById('sec2');
    if (x.style.display == 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var u = document.getElementById("E2");
       u.style.display = "block";
    
    document.getElementById("E2").scrollIntoView();
}
function hideE2ShowS3() {
    var x = document.getElementById('E2');
    if (x.style.display == 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var u = document.getElementById("sec3");
       u.style.display = "block";
}
function hideS3ShowE2() {
    var x = document.getElementById('sec3');
    if (x.style.display == 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var u = document.getElementById("E2");
       u.style.display = "block";
  }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    height: 8000px;
    background-color: white;
}

#intro {
    background-color: black;
}

h1 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: sticky;
    height: 8rem;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    z-index: 1000;
    
}
.s1,s2,s3{
    display:none ;
}
.button {
  background-color: #000000; 
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.b1
{
    height: 170px;
      width: 170px;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      transition: 1s;
      margin-left: 5pt;
      font-size: 30px;
      overflow: scroll;
      color: white;
}
.b1:hover{
    height: 270px;
      width: 270px;
      font-size: 30px;
}

.vertical-center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding-left: 485px;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

a {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
    width: 50px;
    padding-left: 26px;
}
.content {
        padding: 16px;
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-left: 35px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background: transparent;
    }

.ex1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    h2 {
    position: sticky;
    top: 8rem;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.how {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.name {
    position: sticky;
    padding-left: 35px;
    top: 14rem;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.occupation {
    position: sticky;
    padding-left: 35px;
    top: 16rem;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.img {
    display:block;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Portable<br>Digital<br>Format</h1>

<section id="intro">
<p class="content">Portable Digital Format is a curated virtual space founded by Ahmad Saleh to showcase creative talent within the SWANA region. This platform will serve as an easy-to-consume space to explore creative pieces within a portable exhibition that can be accessed anytime, anywhere.</p>
<div>   
    <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="./Assets/instagram.png">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/portabledigitalformat">Follow us on Instagram</a>
</div>
<p class="content">Our first exhibition titled "But I am not an Artist" focuses on creative works done by people who have not been classically trained in any art field. The showcased works are from a variety of fields. The goal of this edition is to highlight creativity in the most unexpected places as these inidividuals have expressed themselves through various media such as acrylic on canvas, sketching, digital art using Adobe Illustrator and other avenues highlighted in the exhibition.<br><br><br><br></p>
<p class="ex1">Exhibition 1</p>
</section>

<h2>BUT I AM NOT AN ARTIST</h2>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<section >
    <div>
    <div id="E1">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="vertical-center"> 
                <p class="how">How would you like to explore?</p>
              <button class="button" ONCLICK="hideDivShowE2()" >Dynamic Explore</button>
             <button class="button" ONCLICK="HideDivShowContent()" >Scroll-to-Explore</button>
            </div>
          </div>
    

</section>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<DIV ID="Participants" STYLE="display:none">
   

<section >
  <h3 class="name">Belmin Mostic</h3>
  <p class="occupation">Consultant and Research Expert</p>

  <img class="img" src="./Assets/belmin.jpeg">
  <img class="img" src="./Assets/Belmin1.jpeg">

</section>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<section >
     
  <h3 class="name">Fatima Lodhi</h3>
  <p class="occupation">Fashion and Multimedia Designer</p>
 
 

    <img class="img" src="./Assets/dreams - fatima lodhi khan.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/euphoria - fatima lodhi khan.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/finefrida - fatima lodhi khan.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/spaceinvasion - fatima lodhi khan.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/reajacobsacrylic - fatima lodhi khan.jpg">
  
  </section>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

<section >
    
  <h3 class="name">Fatima Alhalyan</h3>
  <p class="occupation">Product and Multimedia Designer</p>


  
  <img class="img" src="./Assets/Pink_Lady_2021 - Fatima.png">

</section>


</DIV>
</div>

<!-- ==========================================Page-2==========================================-->


<div>

<DIV ID="E2" STYLE="display:none">
<section>
<div class="container">
   <div class="vertical-center">  
       
        <button class="b1" onclick="hideE2ShowS1()" >I am a Consultant and Research Expert.<br><br>My name is Belmin Mostic.<br>I am from Bosnia.</button>
     <button class="b1" onclick="hideE2ShowS2()" >I am a Fashion and Multimedia Designer.<br><br>My name is Fatima Lodhi.<br>I am from Pakistan.</button>
     <button class="b1" onclick="hideE2ShowS3()" >I am a Product and Multimedia Designer.<br><br>My name is Fatima Alhalyan.<br>I am from the UAE.</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</section>

</DIV>
<!-- S1=================================-->
<section id="sec1" STYLE="display:none">
    <h3 class="name">Belmin Mostic</h3>
    <p class="occupation">Consultant and Research Expert</p>
  
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/belmin.jpeg">
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/Belmin1.jpeg">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div > 
        <button class="button" ONCLICK="hideS1ShowE2()" >Return To Dynamic Explorer</button>
   </div>
            
  
  </section>
  <!-- S2-->

<section id="sec2" STYLE="display:none">
     
  <h3 class="name">Fatima Lodhi</h3>
  <p class="occupation">Fashion and Multimedia Designer</p>
 
 

    <img class="img" src="./Assets/dreams - fatima lodhi khan.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/euphoria - fatima lodhi khan.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/finefrida - fatima lodhi khan.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/spaceinvasion - fatima lodhi khan.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/reajacobsacrylic - fatima lodhi khan.jpg">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div >
        <button class="button" ONCLICK="hideS2ShowE2()" >Return To Dynamic Explorer</button>
        
               
           </div>
            
  </section>

  <!-- S3-->
  <section id="sec3" STYLE="display:none">
    
    <h3 class="name">Fatima Alhalyan</h3>
    <p class="occupation">Product and Multimedia Designer</p>
  
  
    
    <img class="img" src="./Assets/Pink_Lady_2021 - Fatima.png">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div >
        
        <button class="button" ONCLICK="hideS3ShowE2()" >Return To Dynamic Explorer</button>
               
            </div>
            
  
  </section>
```

Comment: Not seeing the images makes it rather hard to see the true output of your website. Would you mind converting them to data URIs or something?